# DropDownListFor Unexpected token u

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm getting a very annoying error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u

I have multiple drop down lists, I'm using `@Html.DropDownListFor()` helper to render it. The error occur as follows:

1- Open one of the drop down list and select an item

2- Open another drop down list then select an item

On step 2 I got the error message but I can't find any thing suspicious or wrong in my code.

Here is how I fill the drop down lists with data (all drop down lists take the same data):

```
 using (Entities context = new Entities())
 {
       ISDCodes = context.ISDCodes.ToList();
 }
 ViewBag.ISDCodes = new SelectList(ISDCodes, "ID", typeTextFieldForISDCode);
```

ISDCode Model:

```
public partial class ISDCode
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string CodeEN { get; set; }
    public string CodeAR { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string PhoneCode { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the Html razor view for these drop down lists:

```
<div class="form-group clearfix">
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-2 control-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Phone1)
        <span class="required">*</span>
    </label>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ISDIDForPhone1, ViewBag.ISDCodes as SelectList, Infas.KFAS.Web.Resources.KFASResources.SelectISDCode,new { id = "ISDIDForPhone1", @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Phone1, new { @class = "form-control", @maxlength = "12", @onkeypress = "keypress(event)", @type = "number" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Phone1)
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group clearfix">
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-2 control-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Phone2)
    </label>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ISDIDForPhone2, ViewBag.ISDCodes as SelectList, Infas.KFAS.Web.Resources.KFASResources.SelectISDCode,new { id = "ISDIDForPhone2", @class = "form-control" })            
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Phone2, new { @class = "form-control", @maxlength = "12", @onkeypress = "keypress(event)", @type = "number" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Phone2)
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where are you seeing this error - in your browser, browser console ...? It looks like a javascript error. Could you post any javascript from this page?

Comment: @Peter I have another dropdownlist for countries in the same page and it's working just fine the only difference is the for countries dropdownlist I'am using ContryName as dataValueField and CountryName as dataTextField.
For ISDIDForPhone1 I'm using ID (int) as dataValueField and ISDCode (string) as dataTextField

Comment: You need to add `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ISDIDForPhone1)` (ditto for `ISDIDForPhone2`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke tried it same error :(

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u` is javascript error. It is generated by `jquery.validate.unobtrusive` if you have controls with data-val` attributes but no associated error placeholder (but could be by generated other javascript code as well). You need to debug your scripts.